# Javascript - Prepend Element when event listener trigger mouse enter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to get some advise from you guys, how can I prepend html element when the event listener listen I mouse enter to the container area. I am using ReactJS to build my frontend. I encounter an issue as I cannot prepend the html element by using the event target which is provided by the callback of the event listener. I have included my code snippet as below:

```
box.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (evt) {
        evt.target.style.border = "unset";
      });
      box.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (evt) {
        evt.target.style.border = "1px solid red";
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        div.style.height = "10px";
        div.style.width = "10px";
        evt.target.parentNode.insertBefore(evt.target,div);
      });
```

In fact, I would like to prepend below div to the container parent whenever I mouseenter the div container.
[image]

I really appreciate your contribution.

Comment: There is a comma on the `evt.target.parentNode.insertBefore(...)` line. 
Also, does the `1px solid red` border work?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately they way you are trying is not the react way.

You need to use state and if statements in your code with **React way**.

Here is a sample for you:

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-tree-1fpjnr

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isShowDiv, setIsShowDiv] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsShowDiv(false)}
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsShowDiv(true)}
    >
      {isShowDiv && (
        <div style={{ background: "red", height: "50px", width: "100%" }}></div>
      )}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Hurricane, but I have more than 1 div can be edited, any advise technique to keep track which div should appear the div when it is mouse enter. If container 2 is mouse enter, the rest container should hide the div.